# Get initial and final position of text inside an element? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn some of jQuery/JS and I get a problem that I can't solve. I have one text like this:

```
blablablabla <b data-start="" data-end="">#foo</b> blablabla"
```

**Note that I can have more than one  tag in this text.**

---

I need edit the  attributes to their right values, so I was constructing a method to do this:

```
// "str" isn't static, but for pratical purposes, I'm using this as static. 
str = 'blablablabla <b data-start="" data-end="">#foo</b> blablabla'

str.children('b').each(function(i){
      $(this).attr('data-start', '');
      $(this).attr('data-end', '');
})
```

As you can see, I don't have idea how I can do the code above. I though use:

```
str.children('b').each(function(i){
          var start = $(this).indexOf('#');
          $(this).attr('data-start', '');
          $(this).attr('data-end', '');
    })
```

But this will return the index `1`, because I'm getting the index of text inside the `b` tag, and not inside the all text itself. So, how I can fix this problem and get initial position of "b" and final position of "b" (excluding the tag itself)?

Comment: Can you describe little more like what should be the final output for your problem? I am not very clear about what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: This is a "highlight" div that is above an textarea element. I will get the textarea cursor position, then `if data-start <= cursorPosition && cursorPosition <= data-end` I will be in this hashtag. So, I must know where's the initial position and the final position of a given hashtag. The expected output is something like `blablablabla <b data-start="23" data-end="26">#foo</b> blablabla` (I don't used the real value for this string, this values is just a example)

Comment: @FernandoPaladini did you check my answer??

Comment: Oh man, sorry, I don't received the notification. Will see now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm.. something like this perhaps..  [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/27QBv/1/)

```
<span id="test" >
blablablabla <b data-start="" data-end="">#foo</b> blablabla" 
</span>
```

and the jquery..

```
var str = $("#test").text();
var strB = $("#test b").text();
$("#test b").attr("data-start", str.indexOf(strB) );
$("#test b").attr("data-end", (str.indexOf(strB) + strB.length-1));
alert($("#test").html())
```

Comment: This helped, but this just works for one hashtag. I adapt your code to my problem and this apparently works! Thanks :)

Comment: @FernandoPaladini no problem.. i didnt knew you had to get many hashtags... anyways.. i'm happy i could be a lil' help..  :D